# How can I combine several imodel 2.0 files into one file?

Tags: imodeljs

How can I combine several imodel 2.0 files into one file?

Comment: Did you try what was recommended in your question in the Github issues? https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/issues/87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IModelTransformer class in the `@bentley/imodeljs-backend`package has the ability to clone/transform elements from a source iModel into a target iModel. You could either:

1. Do 2 transformations to combine 2 source iModels into 1 new target or
2. Merge a source iModel's contents into an existing target.

Please see the documentation here:

https://www.imodeljs.org/learning/backend/imodeltransformation/

Please note that you may need to set up some structure in the target iModel to transform into and some initial remappings. The unit tests here demonstrate some of the required setup:

https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/master/core/backend/src/test/standalone/IModelTransformer.test.ts

If you describe your scenario a bit more, I may be able to provide additional guidance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, it helped me a lot。

Answer (score 1):

Paul Connelly answered already [the same question](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/issues/87) you posted as GitHub issue.

Did you try to use [IModelTransformer class](https://www.imodeljs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeltransformer/) recommended by Paul? This class offers [common i-model ETL functionality](https://www.imodeljs.org/learning/backend/imodeltransformation/?term=imodeltransfor), so using it together with [IModelImporter](https://www.imodeljs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodelimporter/) should allow to merge more i-models into new one.